# Animate slide toggle with pure CSS on jQuery show/hide

Tags: jquery, css

Instead of using pure Javascript to slide toggle

```
$('#div').toggleSlide('fast')
```

I'm looking to just toggle

```
$('#div').toggle()
```

and animate the show/hide slide transitions in CSS. Is that possible without toggling a class to slide in and out?

I know I can add a class and remove like the following but want to try and separate the animations totally from the developers. Right now the designers and developers have to work together to achieve any animation.

```
.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(92, 91, 87, 0.9);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
          transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}

.hidden.open {
  display: block;
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   animation: fade 1s;
}
```

Comment: `Is that possible without toggling a class to slide in and out?` Yes, but toggling the class is by far the easiest and best way to do it

Comment: 1) That's not pure Javascript - it's using jQuery.  2) `.toggle()` just toggles the visible state, so you can't use transitions with it.  3) Toggling a class is the closest to pure CSS you'll get.  I'd strongly recommend doing that, if it's an option.

Comment: Given your update about wanting to separate the design and dev logic - this is exactly why you should toggle the classes on the elements. All the both teams need to know is the class name to change. Devs then toggle it, designers animate it in CSS.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll do that. I was just hoping my googling skills were subpar and that there was a good solution for this. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just get the designers to leave out any transitions from the CSS so hovers and toggles just make things show and hide instantly.  Once the devs are done the designers can tart it up as much as they like by simply adding transitions (as you already have).  They should be working together anyway, as far as I'm concerned.  How else can a team be as effective as possible?  Greater than the sum of their parts, etc..

Answer (score -2):

using `.slideToggle ()` tem allows you to slide again and again belongs to jquery can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: You've definitely not understood the question.